# Easiest way to copy list items and preserve 'Created' in SP2007?

Tags: list, 2007

What is the easiest way to copy list items while preserving the 'Created' information?

Can this somehow be done without code or ps (or without server access)? Saving list as a template with content seems to change the 'Created' value as well as some stsadm extensions with list export capabilities.

Custom site coll admin feature surely is easy to code (as follows) but looking for a more general approach for admins/ site coll admins

```
item["Created"] = created;
item["Author"] = createdBy;
```

Comment: I dont know if there's any free tool. But it's easy to write yourself. I've written a Custom Workflow Activity to do this. So simply run a workflow on an item with the required parameters...

Comment: I was thinking about admin level operations without access to the server. perhaps an easy admin feature for a single admin site would do the trick. added some code to question